# How can data be extracted from this kind of JSON format?

Tags: apex, rest-api, json

How can "orderDetails" be extracted from the following JSON payload?

```
{
    "itemId": "111",
    "count": "20",
    "bookOrders": [
        {
            "bookName": "book1",            
            "bookId": "1234",
            "bookPrintDate": "2015-05-18",
            "orderDetails": {
                "chapter1": "description1",
                "chapter2": "description2"
            }
        },      
        {
            "bookName": "book2",            
            "bookId": "1111",
            "bookPrintDate": "2015-05-20",
            "orderDetails": {
                "chapter1": "description1",
                "chapter2": "description2"
            }
        }        
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Christian's answer is probably the quickest way to do that and it caters for more complex scenarios.

Most of the time I tend to use [json2apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) to generate the class and the parser for me. Depending on the case, sometimes it's more convenient and scalable.

Comment: Bachovski and Christian Deckert your responses were really helpful both the ways works, I think I need to figure out which one works better.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the build in [JSON deserializer](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_Json.htm#apex_System_Json_createParser).

The easiest solution would look like this:

```
String jsonContent = [YOUR JSON CONTENT];
Object jsonObj = Json.deserialize(jsonContent);
List<Object> bookOrders =(List<Object>) ((Map<String, Object>)jsonObj).get('bookOrders');
for(Object bookOrder : bookOrders)
{
    System.debug(bookOrder.get(orderDetails));
}
```

Besides from using the json parser you can consider to use [JSON Parser](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_class_System_JsonParser.htm#apex_System_JsonParser_clearCurrentToken).

Comment: Thanks Chrstian Deckert your response helped me real well. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JSON Parser way:

```
OrdDetails od;
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(jsonString);
while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
    if (parser.getText() == 'orderDetails') {
        while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.START_OBJECT) {
                    od = ( OrdDetails)parser.readValueAs(OrdDetails.class);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

System.debug(od);
```

This depends on there being an OrderDetails object like this:

```
class OrdDetails{
    String chapter1;
    String chapter2;
}
```

Looking at the code of the other questions, in this case definitely, I think using `deserializeUntyped` is going to be quicker and easier to read. As you can see, in my code, there are two nested while loops - not a very maintainable way of parsing JSON! 
Anyway, it's here as the other way to do it.